# MSBuild "Additional properties for project" Error

Tags: c#, msbuild

Having an issue with MSBuild, and hoping someone here can shed a bit of light. I have a solution full of projects. I am building these projects using MSBuild (4.0). No extra configuration file or anything, just MSBuild, on the command line, passing in the solution file as a parameter.

I'm getting this error message (once per project):

> Additional Properties for project "c:...\Project.csproj" [c:...\Solution.sln]

That's it. No error description, no error code; not even a complete statement to go on.

This reproduces only on a specific solution I created recently. It reproduces even when I recreate the solution from scratch, with NO extra configuration or changes from the default. Reproduces regardless of the .NET version. It does not reproduce if I build the projects individually.

Can anyone help me? What in the world does this error mean?

Comment: Are there whitespaces in the path?

Comment: Yes, but there are whitespaces in the paths of most projects/solutions I am working on, and this is the only one with a problem.

Comment: Try building just the project file by itself instead of the solution and see if you still get that error. Also, check your path lengths - try moving the solution closer to the root and see if it compiles. It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You sure this is the **exact** text - its critical for this type of issue? Can you also post the final error summary (e.g from `/ds`).

Is some text in the message triggering the message detection logic which msbuild applies? There's an option (see `msbuild /?`) to disable that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the verbosity to "diagnostic" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

```
/verbosity:diag
```

And have a look at the messages you see immediately before and after your error.

Comment: Tried that. There are actually no messages before or after. Just normal build stuff.